# Optimize Postgres Query with nested join

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that takes several seconds in my staging environment, but takes a few minutes in my production environment.  The query is the same, but the production environment has many more rows in each table (appx 10x).

**The goal of the query** is to find all distinct software records which are installed on at least one of the assets in the search results (NOTE: the search criteria can vary across dozens of fields).

## The tables:

- **Assets**:  dozens of fields on which a user can search - production has several million records
- **InstalledSoftwares**: asset_id (reference), software_id (reference) - each asset has 10-100 installed software records, so there are 10s of millions of records in production.
- **Softwares**: the results. Production has less than 4000 unique software records.

I've removed duplicate WHERE clauses based on the suggestions from Laurenz Albe.
How can I make this more efficient?

## The Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "softwares"."id" FROM "softwares" 
INNER JOIN "installed_softwares" ON "installed_softwares"."software_id" = "softwares"."id" 
WHERE "installed_softwares"."asset_id" IN 
  (SELECT "assets"."id" FROM "assets" 
   WHERE "assets"."assettype_id" = 3 
   AND "assets"."archive_number" IS NULL
   AND "assets"."expired" = FALSE 
   AND "assets"."local_status_id" != 4 
   AND "assets"."scorable" = TRUE)
```

## Here is the EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers) for the query:

```
Unique  (cost=153558.09..153588.92 rows=5524 width=8) (actual time=4224.203..5872.293 rows=3525 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=112428 read=187, temp read=3145 written=3164
  I/O Timings: read=2.916
  ->  Sort  (cost=153558.09..153573.51 rows=6165 width=8) (actual time=4224.200..5065.158 rows=1087807 loops=1)
        Sort Key: softwares.id
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 19240kB
        Buffers: shared hit=112428 read=187, temp read=3145 written=3164
        I/O Timings: read=2.916
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=119348.05..153170.01 rows=6165 width=8) (actual time=342.860..3159.458 rows=1087807 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (installed_softwares.software_id = softwares.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=112428 read=187
              I/O Timings: read=2.916
              ->  Gather  (cost=119119.76..152925.53 rows=6165 width=8) (actual time=333.981..1320.277 rows=1087807 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 2
                    Workers Launched: 2
                    Buffers: shared hit=112324 read=187
                    I/O Timings: read=2.916
                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=118119.76..151309.03 rows=2569 width=8) (actual time=331.836..2010.171 rows=362602 loops=3)
                          Hash Cond: (installed_softwares.asset_id = assets.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=112324 read=187
                          I/O Timings: read=2.916
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on installed_softwares  (cost=0.00..30518.88 rows=1017288 width=16) (actual time=0.007..667.564 rows=813396 loops=3)
                                Buffers: shared hit=20159 read=187
                                I/O Timings: read=2.916
                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=118065.04..118065.04 rows=4378 width=4) (actual time=331.648..331.651 rows=23407 loops=3)
                                Buckets: 131072 (originally 16384)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 4672kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=92058
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on assets  (cost=0.00..118065.04 rows=4378 width=4) (actual time=0.012..302.134 rows=23407 loops=3)
                                      Filter: ((archive_number IS NULL) AND (NOT expired) AND scorable AND (local_status_id <> 4) AND (assettype_id = 3))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1363624
                                      Buffers: shared hit=92058
              ->  Hash  (cost=159.24..159.24 rows=5524 width=8) (actual time=8.859..8.862 rows=5546 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 281kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=104
                    ->  Seq Scan on softwares  (cost=0.00..159.24 rows=5524 width=8) (actual time=0.006..4.426 rows=5546 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=104
Planning Time: 0.534 ms
Execution Time: 5878.476 ms
```

Comment: VACUUM ANALYZE "assets" and see if anything changes.  There is no point in digging deeper until we know that that doesn't fix it.

Comment: What is the plan on the staging server?

Comment: The slowest part is the sort on disk, what happens when you change to setting for work_mem to let's say one GB? SET work_mem TO '1GB'; and then do your query. But the biggest problem is the plan itself

Comment: running VACUUM ANALYZE assets had no effect on the performance.  Also, this plan is for the staging server.

Comment: Since this is running in AWS on a shared database, it's difficult to adjust the work_mem.  I could get it done if there is a general agreement that this would be a huge fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the bad row count estimate for the scan on `assets`. The estimate is so bad (48 rows instead of 23407), because the condition is somewhat redundant:

```
archived_at IS NULL AND archive_number IS NULL AND
NOT expired AND
scorable AND
local_status_id <> 4 AND local_status_id <> 4 AND
assettype_id = 3
```

PostgreSQL treats all these conditions as statistically independent, which leads it astray. One of the conditions (`local_status_id <> 4`) is present twice; remove one copy. The first two conditions seem somewhat redundant too; perhaps one of them can be omitted.

Perhaps that is enough to improve the estimate so that PostgreSQL does not choose the slow nested loop join.

Comment: This change does result in a 25% performance improvement in staging.  I'll update my question to show the new plan.

Comment: When making this change in production, the results come back in under 10 seconds where it was originally taking several minutes.  This has solved it!